# Does Spring Cloud Stream project needs web server (Tomcat) or not?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-messaging, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using **Spring Cloud Stream** to write messaging-driven microservices.

- Project A: Producer (Spring Cloud Stream, integrated tomcat and its port: 8080)
- Project B: Consumer (Spring Cloud Stream, integrated tomcat and its port: 8081)
- Message Broker: RabbitMQ (amqp port: 5672)

My question is: 
For project A & B, do them need integrated web server/port (Tomcat) or not? Or just a common java application would be fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to access Boot's web support (actuator etc), you can disable the web using the [application builder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-fluent-builder-api).

Simply add

```
.web(false)
```

before the `run()`.

Alternatively, just set `remote.port=0` and a random port will be selected for each.